# Rip-tide of downvotes and being closed makes it hard to sup in the freedom of asking

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality

Every single question I have asked on Stack Exchange has been down-voted, closed or marked as off-topic. At first I tried wording my questions better, then I tried asking fewer questions. Then I tried using better content.

Regardless of what I do I get down-voted and most of the time no answers.

Isn't there freedom of asking on Stack Exchange?

What's the point of asking questions and thinking them through for hours and getting that treatment? Must everything be worded/written to a specific standard?

If so, how do I ask a question on any of the 300 something sites without getting all of the off-topic/no reply treatment?

Please give me an answer, don't comment with a link to support as I've gotten a link and read that page 100x already.

Comment: Did you read through your first version of this question? And did you just slap on those tags because?

Comment: Title was not changed by me. And it would not let me post without those tags.

Comment: If the original state of this question is like what you normally post, then it's not hard to see why you're getting downvotes

Comment: Poor choice in tags, spelling, grammar, sentence structure, these all can mean some things worth downvoting over. No, there is no freedom, it's a privilege to ask on Stack Exchange, not a right.

Comment: @random thanks for explaining.

Comment: I noticed that some of your questions were closed as off-topic, and that you don't have the [informed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed) badge on any sites, which you get for reading the "About" page on a site. Maybe doing that would help give you a better idea of what questions each site is looking for.

Comment: Alright thanks for that, but how can I find the about page for each site?

Comment: Use the "help" drop-down bar at the top of the page. Select "Tour."

Comment: Thanks for the info much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I was about to downvote this too and vote to close as "does not appear to seek input and discussion" aka "pure rant" however on second thought, maybe you do deserve an answer.

I did not look on your questions on any other site just yet, don't think I should since I can tell you the answer to your questions even without it.

> Isn't there freedom of asking on Stack Exchange?

Yes, there is. And there is also freedom of voting - either up or down.

> If so, how do I ask a question on any of the 300 something sites without getting all of the off-topic/no reply treatment?

You read the help center of each site (e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), there is a part explaining what questions are on topic on each site. Most likely you ask **off topic questions** meaning that even a question you researched for whole days and written without a single typo might get closed simply for not belonging to the site. Example out of the top of my head, any tool recommendation question on Stack Overflow would suffer such a fate.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but please don't get me wrong, I honestly don't mind people down voting what I mind is people down voting and me not understanding / knowing why. I what to know how I can ask a question properly on any site and this answer has provided some info as to why I get the stated results thank you, your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: Cheers @Malik, I've added a relevant link now.

Comment: So I've read it and understood a lot more, once again thanks 